# Boto (Python)- reversed bucket list

Tags: python, list, amazon-s3, boto, bucket

Does anyone know how to get reversed bucket list.

```
bucketList = self.bucket.list(PREFIX)
bucketList.reverse()
```

does not work.

Thanks,
Ron.

Comment: You mean `list(reversed(bucketList))` ?

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work also: TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence

Comment: Can you add the result of "print bucketList" to your question?

Comment: <boto.s3.bucketlistresultset.BucketListResultSet instance at 0x1016b70e0>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you can't do a reverse of bucket.list() is because that method actually returns a generator rather than the actual list.  This is much more efficient and also allows boto to handle all of the paging of results behind the scenes.

If you really want to reverse it you could collect all of the elements in a list and then reverse that:

```
objs = [obj for obj in self.bucket.list(PREFIX)]
objs.reverse()
```

but if there are a lot of objects in the bucket this will be very inefficient.